# Node sizes not correct when drawing a graph with many components

Tags: python, networkx, graph-visualization

I've got a graph with many components which I would like to visualize. As a special feature, the node dots of the nodes in the giant component shall scale with their eigenvector centrality. All the other nodes have same size.

I use the following script:

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H = nx.read_gexf(input_file)
print nx.info(H)
#Name: 
#Type: Graph
#Number of nodes: 719
#Number of edges: 620
#Average degree:   1.7246

# Set draw() parameters
node_sizes = dict.fromkeys(H.nodes(), 0.005)
# Make node size of giant component nodes proportional to their eigenvector
eigenvector = nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy(G)
for node, value in eigenvector.iteritems():
    node_sizes[node] = round(value, 4)
node_sizes = [v*2000 for v in node_sizes.values()] # rescale
node_positions = nx.pygraphviz_layout(H, prog="neato")

# Draw graph with different color for each connected subgraph
plt.figure(3, figsize=(90,90))
nx.draw(H, font_size=10, pos=node_positions, node_size=node_sizes, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Everything is quite correct, as I checked in distinct outputs. However, I receive an output where some nodes from components other than the giant component are scale. Moreover, the nodes in the giant component are not correctly scaled.

This snapshot shows the giant component and an off-component with a scaled node:
[image]

However, if I only print the giant component `G` using the dictionary `eigenvector` for the node size, I get the following - correct - output (:

[image]

I did some troubleshooting, too. For example, the dictionary/list `node_sizes` is all correct. Interestingly, using a random graph `H = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(300, 0.005, seed=5)` returns correct results. Therefore I have absolutely no idea what's wrong with my `H`.

Comment: I've provided an answer - but haven't tested it since I don't have your input network.  Please check it and let me know - especially if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll notice that `node_sizes` is a list.  You haven't sent the draw command a list of nodes.  It's going to generate them on the fly from the nodes in the network.  The problem occurs when these two lists end up being in different orders.  I don't think it's an issue with having multiple components, but rather the larger your network is the more likely it is that they aren't put into the same order.

So rather than

```
node_sizes = [v*2000 for v in node_sizes.values()]
```

use

```
nodelist, node_sizes = zip(*node_sizes.items())
```

here nodelist will get the list of the first numbers in each entry of node_sizes.items and node_sizes will get the list of the second numbers in each entry.

Then in the plotting command give it the nodelist

```
nx.draw(H, font_size=10, pos=node_positions, node_size=node_sizes, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, with_labels=True, nodelist=nodelist)
```

Comment: It works. I expected something like that - where else could the error have been. To scale the node sizes (I used a factor of 2000), one now has to multiply in the eigenvector loop as well as in in the initialization of the `node_sizes` dictionary.