# Node sizes varying between runs, while data is not changing between runs

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, networkx

edit2: So I cross checked with another set of data, and I am not experiencing this node variability when I only have one set of nodes, but for some reason this method isn't productive. I can't understand why this is happening, examining the source code for different parts has not yielded any insights about bugs.

edit3: I forgot to check one part of the other data set, I never created subgroups for it. Now that I have those subgroups, I am experiencing the same node size variations. So it has to do with how networkx/matplotlib plots onto an axis repeatedly. Still no progress. I want to make a specific note: The node variability only appears to take effect after the first set of nodes is drawn.

edit3.5: So it may not be so much as which one is drawn first, but which group they belong too. I have no idea what is happening.

edit4: I explicitly double checked the data being put into `draw_nodes` and it checks out. I was reading over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438584/node-sizes-not-correct-when-drawing-a-graph-with-many-components) that sometimes values can be misplaced in an ordered list and explicitly checked for misordered elements. It's simply not the case. I am passing into `draw_nodes` basically and identical version of a previous attempt. In fact, in a working previous attempt I used the same list comprehension technique and had no issues creating lists. Here I am using numpy to make the same lists, but I can't find issues in the data.

edit5: I just wanted to mention that I added print readouts to see what data was being passed where into some of the internals of matplotlib and the data was not being mutated at least through collections.py in the matplotlib package. The draw_nodes quickly connects to PathCollection in collections.py, but I lose track of what's going on once I follow the data to the class `Collection`.

---

I have a networkx graphic that I am putting together, and for some unknown reason when I run the same piece of code just a minute after the previous run, changing nothing about any data or code, the node sizes will vary dramatically.

See the three attached runs.[image][image][image]

The relevant code is here, and exists within a simple for look counting the various color coded groups (plot_nodes is just a wrapper for nx.draw_networkx_nodes):

```
indicies = where( equal( codes, i ) )
sub_nodes = color_coding[ indicies, 0 ].astype( str ).flatten( )
new_pos = { key : pos[ key ] for key in sub_nodes }
G = graph.subgraph( sub_nodes )
plot_nodes( G, new_pos,
            node_list=sub_nodes,
            ax=plt,
            cmap=node_cmap[ i ],
            node_size=node_sizes[ indicies ] * node_scalar,
            node_color=node_colors[ indicies ],
            edgecolors='black', with_labels=False,
            alpha=.8,
            )
```

When i inspect the sizes being passed into the plotting with `print(node_sizes[ indicies ]*node_scalar)` tacked above the plot function, I see that the data is consistent across runs, and that the values being given to the function are the same. The even crazier part is when I set `node_size=300` I do not get random nodes.

edit: I found out I can set vmin and vmax, but that didn't change anything and the random nodes is still a problem.

Comment: My guess would be that you have a misalignment between the node sizes and the actual nodes, i.e., that the nodes are drawn with the different sizes, but not the correct ones. To fix this, you would need to make sure, that the order of values supplied as node size list agrees with the order of `G.nodes`. We would need a minimal reproducible working example to easier help you.

Comment: @Sparky05, I have managed to put together an MVP. Would you like me to add it to the top of the post?

Comment: Yes, include it via editing in your post as you've done before. Make sure that no names or similar are included. Hopefully, it's anyways not too long ;)